# Text messages react-native

Tags: react-native

What are the ways one would access text messages in React native app.ofcourse the user would need to give permissions.

But i am wondering if there are strict restrictions that prevent apps from accessing text messages. are there libraries that I can use in react native?

what are the differences between android and ios.

I expect that there are policies to follow

Comment: You cannot access text messages at all on iOS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.